Material3 dynamic color not working in compose for Android API 34
I'm making a project in Android with Jetpack Compose. I want to use a dynamic color theme but it's not working for Android API level 34 (it works well on 32-33). Dynamic colors are not working in the preview as well as any API 34 device.
I've confirmed that my SDK tools are well-upgraded.
Can anyone help regarding the issue?
versions:
kotlin = "1.9.0"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2024.05.00"
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3", version = "1.2.1" }

@Preview(
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES,
    apiLevel = 33,
    wallpaper = Wallpapers.RED_DOMINATED_EXAMPLE,
    name = "API 33",
)

@Preview(
    uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES,
    apiLevel = 34,
    wallpaper = Wallpapers.RED_DOMINATED_EXAMPLE,
    name = "API 34",
)

@Composable
fun HomeScreenPreview() {
    HomeScreen()
}

Output:

I tried to clean the build and remake whole project. Also installed the latest tools.

It seems that you are using Android Studio preview tools instead of the  physical  android device running

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
